# Architecture - should my Main Activity know about my app specific fragments?

Tags: java, android, architecture

I'm trying to learn more about proper architecture so I'm going to try to refactor some of my working code. I have an android app that swaps in a few different Fragments for the main view. Right now, the different fragments exist as properties in MainActivity. When the user picks a menu item I have to check what kind of Fragment is currently being shown (via instanceof) and perform some different tasks depending on what kind of fragment it is. It's pretty ugly and I feel like it should be better abstracted. In the future, the case statement will grow even more and need to be maintained. Also, most of the code is duplicated since I only really need to do something special for one fragment in particular. How can I abstract away these details out of MainActivity? I tried to make a base class for all my fragments but it didn't quite work out because some of the fragments extend MapFragment and some just extend Fragment. So I'm guessing an interface is the way to go but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Do I need to create an abstract factory to get these objects in MainActivity? What is the proper way to do this? After reading up a little bit on architecture, it seems to me that my MainActivity should only know about some abstractions for my Fragments and not the concrete classes themselves, is that correct? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think you can create: an interface first for all and two or more abstract base classes for each type of fragment. Every fragment will extend your abstract base class.

Comment: Furthering on @AnhNguyenNgoc's point, each fragment should be completely responsible for what it needs so the MainActivity should be able to just directly call the fragment and tell it to run whatever it needs to run. Thus, the MainActivity has just one call on a fragment change and can polymorphically change behaviour based on the needs of the Fragment.